# Restart issues with iMac and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mac

When I select "restart" with 12.04 it begins the process, then stays forever stuck on the 3rd or 4th "dot" with the Ubuntu logo and never restarts so I don't have a choice but to force my iMac to shutdown.

Couldn't see any report of this issue anywhere. Does it ring a bell to someone? And is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe ACPI is not enabled

1. try to shutdown using `sudo shutdown -h now`
2. update your bios (if applicable)
3. install acpi using `sudo apt-get install acpid` and try to shutdown again
4. when the shutdown hangs press the left arrow key to see the diagnostics

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't seem to work. 1/ `sudo shutdown -h now` shuts down the computer (which works fine) but the problem I have is with restarts only 2/ acpid is already installed and the left arrow key didn't trigger anything.